# Remove manifest permissions in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, manifest, permissions, administrator

I have been developing a C# windows form application in XP.  It all works just fine.  But in Vista it was not able to write the log or scoreboard file to the hard drive.  I found out that I needed a manifest file to allow the popup to ask it to be run as admin.

This all worked well and I am very pleased.  My problem is I do not know how to remove this permission so that I can repeat the test and change the situation slightly.

Does anyone know how I remove the permission the manifest file gave the EXE please as I do not get the do you want it to run as admin popup now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest doesn't give any specific permission to the module. The manifest is inserted as a resource in the module and is then. If you need to repeat the test - just open the file with a resource editor and delete and MANIFEST resources you can see.